# How can I reach a Facebook app by it's ID?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I'm working on a Facebook application.
I have the ID of the application but I don't know how to reach it. 
How can I find it by it's id?

Comment: Did you find out how to reach this ?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I absolutely forgot my question here, anyway you were right.

Comment: dont worry about the question. It's more about validating that what I say is correct as well. It's good to validate an answer because the person then knows that his opinion was correct. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean exactely find it by id?

```
https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=yourappid
```

the above link will show the app.